# Name a variable on the fly

Tags: php

I am accepting a variable into a function.

For example, the variable is called `$field` and I then want to name a variable by what is inside the `$field` variable.

Say `$field = 'randomName'`, I want my variable to be `$randomName`.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

```
$field = "randomName";
$$field = "test";
$$$field = "test 2";
echo $randomName . "\n"; //outputs: "test"
echo $test. "\n"; //outputs: "test 2"
```

Check **[this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)** out

Answer (score 1):

```
$field = "randomName" ;
${$field} = "yeah" ;
```

---

```
${"randomName"} = "that works too" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (see ["variable variables"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)), but *this approach should be discouraged* and it is often better to use a data structure (i.e. an [array with keys](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)) for this sort of dynamic operation.

Comment: Why should it be discouraged? I couldn't achieve what I need to using an array.

Comment: I'd really like to see something you cannot achieve using arrays?

Comment: @Luke Because it is *usually* the wrong approach. How many languages have "variable variables", or a direct equivalent? *Very few*. Yet there is no problem using Maps (i.e. PHP/array, Java/HashMap, Perl/hash, Python/Dictionary) to solve the exact same issue. Of course, the real issue trying to be solved might be .. special: make sure to include applicable context in posts.

Comment: I fully agree with this. Magically instantiated / altered variables are a bane for your fellow coders, hard to track, hard to debug, and as said: an array usually solves these _without_ driving colleagues mad.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a language feature called [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). In your case:

```
$field = 'randomName';

$$field = "Hello world!";

echo $randomName; // prints out "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want variable variables?

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Example

```
$varname = 'var';
$$varname = 'content';
print $var; // outputs 'content'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign variables as variable names.

```
$$field
```

This will do what it sounds like you're asking for.